# Django 3 Несколько моделей во view - Page not found (404)

Tags: django, view, model

Есть 2 модели Category и Tag, которые хотелось бы выводить в 1 view.

model 1

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
""" Category"""
name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=75, unique=True, blank=True)
parent = TreeForeignKey(
    "self",
    verbose_name="Родительская категория",
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    related_name='children'
)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = gen_slug(self.name)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}"

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("category_detail_url", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Категория"
    verbose_name_plural = "Категории"
    ordering = ['id']
```

model 2

```
class Tag(MPTTModel):
""" Tag """
name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=75, unique=True, blank=True)
category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='tag_category_rn', blank=True)
parent = TreeForeignKey(
    "self",
    verbose_name="Родительский тэг",
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    related_name='children'
)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = gen_slug(self.name)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}"

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("category_detail_url", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Тэг"
    verbose_name_plural = "Тэги"
    ordering = ['id']
```

view

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView, MultipleObjectMixin):
""" Single Category """
model = Category
slug = "url"
paginate_by = 21

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    object_list = AddVideo.objects.all()
    context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(object_list=object_list, **kwargs)
    context['tag'] = Tag.objects.all()
    return context
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
path('<slug:slug>', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name="category_detail_url"),
]
```

Проблема в том, что объекты из модели Category отображаются нормально, а из модели Tag выдает ошибку:

Page not found (404)

slug:slug [name='category_detail_url']

The current path, tag-1, matched the last one.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Как по вашему view должна определить, что нужно выводить имеено эту модель а не другую? и добавьте urls.py

Comment: В этом, собственно, и есть вопрос - можно ли сделать так, чтобы понимал или это лучше сделать как-то по другому? (urls добавил)

Comment: Сделать то можно, но нужны ли такие костыли?
Для этого можно использовать self.kwargs.get('url'). В get_queryset() смотрите, есть ли категории с url, а потом смотрите тоже самое по тегам. Объединить queryset'ы можно так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411049/how-can-i-find-the-union-of-two-django-querysets

Comment: Благодарю. Наверное, откажусь от этого, так как там много чего другого тоже не склеивается.